I think armhf updates are not being retrieved. :-(
This happened a few weeks ago when security updates suddently stopped. Does anyone have a solution?
/etc/apt/sources.list is ...
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security multiverse

This is what happens:
myron@loki:/etc/apt$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/eivnaes/network-manager-sstp/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [128 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [129 kB]
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:4 http://xogium.performanceservers.nl/apt jammy InRelease
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [127 kB]
Hit:6 https://github.armbian.com/configurator stable InRelease
E: Repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Armbian' to 'Ubuntu'
E: Repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from 'Armbian' to 'Ubuntu'
N: Repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' changed its 'Version' value from '' to '22.04'
N: Repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'jammy' to 'jammy-updates'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N] y
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main armhf Packages
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main armhf DEP-11 Metadata [134 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [37.5 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [56.8 kB]
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted armhf DEP-11 Metadata [159 B]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe armhf Packages
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe armhf DEP-11 Metadata [491 kB]
E: Repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Armbian' to 'Ubuntu'
E: Repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from 'Armbian' to 'Ubuntu'
N: Repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease' changed its 'Version' value from '' to '22.04'
N: Repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from 'jammy' to 'jammy-security'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N] y
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [247 kB]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [398 kB]
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse armhf DEP-11 Metadata [159 B]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [1,867 B]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [2,497 B]
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main armhf Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe armhf Packages
Ign:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main armhf Packages
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main armhf DEP-11 Metadata [53.6 kB]
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Get:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [16.9 kB]
Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [26.5 kB]
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted armhf Packages
Get:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted armhf DEP-11 Metadata [155 B]
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main armhf Packages
Get:31 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]
Get:32 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]
Ign:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe armhf Packages
Get:34 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe armhf DEP-11 Metadata [163 kB]
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Get:35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [82.0 kB]
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe armhf Packages
Get:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [122 kB]
Ign:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Get:38 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse armhf DEP-11 Metadata [157 B]
Get:39 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]
Get:40 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]
Ign:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main armhf Packages
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe armhf Packages
Ign:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main armhf Packages
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe armhf Packages
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main armhf Packages
Ign:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main armhf Packages
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe armhf Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main armhf Packages
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe armhf Packages
Ign:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Err:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::102 80]
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe armhf Packages
Ign:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe armhf Packages
Ign:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main armhf Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe armhf Packages
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe armhf Packages
Ign:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main armhf Packages
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main armhf DEP-11 Metadata [602 kB]
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [100.0 kB]
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [148 kB]
Ign:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe armhf Packages
Get:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe armhf DEP-11 Metadata [5,082 kB]
Get:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3,447 kB]
Get:49 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7,609 kB]
Ign:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse armhf Packages
Get:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse armhf DEP-11 Metadata [44.8 kB]
Get:52 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [42.7 kB]
Get:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [193 kB]
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main armhf Packages
Ign:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe armhf Packages
Ign:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main armhf Packages
Get:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main armhf DEP-11 Metadata [3,711 B]
Get:56 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [9,524 B]
Get:57 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [11.2 kB]
Get:58 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/restricted armhf DEP-11 Metadata [159 B]
Get:59 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/restricted DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]
Get:60 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]
Ign:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe armhf Packages
Get:62 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe armhf DEP-11 Metadata [19.6 kB]
Get:63 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [19.7 kB]
Get:64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [28.2 kB]
Get:65 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/multiverse armhf DEP-11 Metadata [161 B]
Get:66 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]
Get:67 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]
Ign:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main armhf Packages
Ign:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe armhf Packages
Ign:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main armhf Packages
Ign:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe armhf Packages
Ign:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main armhf Packages
Ign:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe armhf Packages
Ign:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main armhf Packages
Ign:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe armhf Packages
Ign:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main armhf Packages
Ign:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe armhf Packages
Ign:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main armhf Packages
Ign:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe armhf Packages
Ign:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse armhf Packages
Err:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
Ign:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe armhf Packages
Ign:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main armhf Packages
Ign:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe armhf Packages
Ign:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse armhf Packages
Err:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
Ign:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe armhf Packages
Fetched 1,497 kB in 19s (79.8 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::102 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2620:2d:4002:1::103 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.


Your sources are incorrect; armhf packages are found in the port repository and not the main archive...   Your system sources are incorrect if you're using an ARM processor (main archive contains only amd64 and i386; ports contains packages for armhf, arm64, riscv64, ppc64el, s390x, riscv64..  ie. your sources should say https://ports.ubuntu.com/ )
